# ffmpeg - add 3 audio streams to video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have the following problem.
In the folder there is video.mp4 file (contain 1 audio stream). There are also 3 different files audio1.wav, audio2.wav, audio3.wav. These files I need to 'attach' as multi stream to the video file - so the user can choose the audio language in VLC player or similar. Result must be one audio at the time - no mixing it all together.

Now, I've done it via Premiere Pro with multitrack (quicktime export to mov), and then I run a script to change audio stream names to correspond with the audio language (iso 639-2 ) and output the mp4 file. All works well, but I wonder if there is simple way to do everything via ffmpeg ( .bat script ). I have a working script for replacing audio in the video, but I need to add few additional .wav to the video file as separate audio tracks.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To **add** a new audio track into an existing video with audio, use

the `-i` parameter to specify all the input files (original video and additional audios)

the `-map` option to manually select the tracks of each input (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

in your case,
`-map 0` to copy all streams from the input #0  (video)
`-map 1:a` to include all audio streams from input#1 file (audio1)
`-map 2:a` to include all audio streams from input#2 file (audio2)
and so on

and

`-shortest` to crop the output to the shortest input

and *additionally* you may want to use
`-c:v copy` to copy the video stream without reencoding.

so, try this (line split for readability)

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 
        -map 0 -map 1:a -map 2:a 
        -c:v copy -shortest 
        output.mp4
```

and (addording to your comment) adding metadata for the audio tracks

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 
       -map 0 -map 1:a -map 2:a 
       -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng
       -metadata:s:a:1 language=ger
       -metadata:s:a:2 language=fra 
       -disposition:a:0 default
       -c:v copy -shortest 
       output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
Is it any different if there are wavs instead of mp3?
I found earlier line very similar to yours and made modification so I can open this in the same folder as files are but does not work :( <br/>
`set output=Output
set audio_format=wav
if not exist %output% ( mkdir %output% )
for %%F in (*.mkv) do ( 
ffmpeg -i Howto.mkv -i Howto_DE.wav -i Howto_FR.wav -i Howto_JP.wav -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=ger -metadata:s:a:2 language=fra -metadata:s:a:3 language=jpn -codec copy HowtoMultiAu.mp4 )
pause`

Comment: thank you thank you!! I made for loop and everything works now , even with .wav files. For apple quicktime compatibility I added such parameter : `-disposition:a:0 default' and before that '-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng ` to claim languages to be visible properly

Comment: please upvote and accept, so new visitors to this question will know it's been solved

Comment: I've tried but i get this: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @PA. there is a small typo in the answer in the last command - `map 0` -> `-map 0`